# WPF ¿Por qué no se muestra el valor seleccionado en los elementos DataGridComboBoxColumn de un DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, combobox, datagrid

Estoy elaborando un programa **WPF** en el que requiero mostrar una tabla, para lo que decidí utilizar un `DataGrid`, en la que una sus columnas es un `DataGridComboBoxColumn` el cual debe estar asociado al valor de la columna anterior para lograr que el usuario pueda agregar únicamente datos coherentes, para llenar los datos del `DataGrid` estoy utilizando una `DataTable`, el problema es que cuando asocio el nombre de la columna que contiene los valores a mostrar con la propiedad `DisplayMemberPath`, no se muestra el valor seleccionado en el ComboBox, pero cuando despliego sí se muestran los valores que debería contener:

Aquí se muestra lo que se ve al seleccionar una opción del ComboBox

[image: Opción ya seleccionada. No muestra nada el ComboBox]

Aquí se muestra que si existen elementos seleccionables:

[image: Opción 2 de datos filtrados]

estoy configurando el `DataGridComboBox` de la siguiente forma:

```csharp
DataGridComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();

comboBoxColumn.Header = columnName;
comboBoxColumn.DisplayMemberPath = dataColumn;
comboBoxColumn.SelectedValuePath = columnName;
comboBoxColumn.ItemsSource = table1.DefaultView;
comboBoxColumn.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(indexColumn);
```

Donde:

- `columnName` es una variable que contiene el nombre de la columna que contiene el índice
- `dataColumn` es una variable que contiene el nombre de la columna que contiene el valor de interés
- `indexColumn` es una variable que contiene el nombre de la columna que contiene el índice del valor inicial que debería mostrar el `DataGridComboBoxColumn`
- `table1` es el nombre del `DataTable` de referencia

Tengo la teoria de que el único problema es la forma de enlazar la propiedad `DisplayMemberPath`

¿Alguién podría asesorarme o mostrarme otro camino para realizar lo que necesito?